# Does THIS prior art invalidate THIS patent application?

Tags: prior-art-request, prior-art, patentability, us20130189631

[image]

[Here](http://ahhha.com/idea/slide-release-buckle-fire-starter/) is an example of an invention website where a poster presents the idea of a "Slide Release Buckle + Fire Starter", dated April 18, 2011.

The application in question is "Quick-Release Buckle with Fire Starting Components"(Publication Number: [US20130189631 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130189631?dq=fire+starter+buckle&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x_IoUvb1M8Xd4APO-YCQDQ&sqi=2&pjf=1&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA)) by Michael John MOJICA claiming a priority to the U.S. Provisional Patent application submitted January 19, 2012, whereas claim 1 is as follows "A quick-release buckle with fire starting components..."

[image: www.hikepro.com also makes claims to having invented a buckle with a fire starter in 2007]

The image above is a screen shot from a page on http://www.hikepro.net describing the history of creating a buckle with a fire starter. It dates the invention to 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

US20130189631 is not a patent, 
it is an application for a patent. If the person behind the posting is not the inventor of the application and isn't someone who got it from the inventor then it would likely knock out the application. If it was from the inventor then it looks like it was within the 1 year grace period and not usable as prior art. Under the "old" patent law in effect then your own work can't be used against you for a year. Now, under AIA, it is more complicated.